# Python3 get key from dict.items() maximum value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm not a Python programmer. Having a Python3 dictionary like this,

```
d={"a":"1", "b":"2"}
```

How can I get the key for the largest value (that is, 'b') in a simple form?

Of course, I can write some spaghetti,

```
def get_max_key(data):
    MAX=''
    MAXKEY=''
    for x in data.items():
        if x[1]>MAX:    
            MAX=x[1]
            MAXKEY=x[0]
    return MAXKEY
```

But that's silly. I know there should be a pythonic way to do it, possibly a one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the key of the maximum value in a dictionary, just use this:

```
max(d, key=d.get)
```